# jQuery getJSON not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: getjson

I have a site that uses jQuery within the Codeigniter framework. It works perfectly in both Firefox and Chrome. However in IE the getJSON does not work, jQuery load() works but not getJSON. Ive tried the $.ajaxSetup{{cache:false}} among others but no joy.

```js
var url="../../index.php/cslcontrol/";

$(document).ready(function(){

  //hide divs with the class '.views' except the one with id of 'home'
  $(".views:not('#home')").hide();
  //function that ensures only the div related to the selected menubar icon is dislayed
  $("li a[href]").click(function(){
    //storing the value of the clicked list a href
    var tabVal=$(this).attr('value');
    //showing a div whose div name is the same as the value of the selected list ahref
    $("#"+tabVal).show();
    //keeping the other divs hidden
    $(".views[id!="+tabVal+"]").hide();
  });

  $("#home_text").load("css/history.html #home_txt");

  $("#eighties_text").load("images/Eighties_seasons.html h1, p");
  
  $("#nineties_text").load("images/Nineties_seasons.html h1, p");

//making a ajax call to fill the champions table
  $.getJSON(url+"titleWin", function(data){
   $.each(data, function(){
    $("#senior_champions").append("<tr><td>"+ this["Season"] + "</td><td>"+ this["Winner"] + "</td><td>" + this["Runner up"] + "</td><td>"+ this["Play off"] + "</td></tr>");
    });
  });
  //making a ajax call to fill the senior cup table
  $.getJSON(url+"senCup", function(data){
   $.each(data, function(){
    $("#senior_cup_finals").append("<tr><td>"+ this["Season"] + "</td><td>"+ this["Winner"] + "</td><td>" + this["Score"] + "</td><td>"+ this["Runner-up"] + "</td></tr>");
    });
  });
  $.getJSON(url+"getClub", function(data){
   $.each(data, function(){
    $("#club_info").append("<a class=\"name\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modalCSL\">"+this["Club"]+"</a>");
    });
   var crests = [];
   $.each(data, function(){
    if(this["Image"]!=""){
      crests.push("<img src=\"images/"+this["Image"]+"\" alt=\""+this["Image"]+"\" title=\""+this["Club"]+"\"/>");
    }
   });
   $("#pix1").html(crests.slice(0, 5));
   $("#pix2").html(crests.slice(5, 10));
   $("#pix3").html(crests.slice(10, 15));
  });
});

$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event,xhr,settings){
  //if(settings.url=="history.txt"){
    // $("#home_text").append("<div class=\"home-images\">do</div>");
  //}

  if(settings.url==url+"senCup"){
    $("#senior_cup_finals td:eq(26), #senior_cup_finals td:eq(30)").append("<a href=\"#calry_merv\"><sup> R</sup></a>");
    $("#senior_cup_finals td:eq(34)").append("<a href=\"#salt_calry\"><sup> R-p</sup></a>");
  }
  if(settings.url==url+"titleWin"){
    $("#champions td:eq(11)").append("<a href=\"#merv_salt\"><sup> R</sup></a>");
    $("#champions td:eq(52)").append("<a href=\"#straide\"><sup> Gr</sup></a>");
    $("#champions td:eq(56)").append("<a href=\"#prem\"><sup> Pr</sup></a>");
  }
  if(settings.url==url+"getClub"){
      $(".name").click(function(){
        var aref= $(this).text();
        $(".modal-body").load("css/history.html h1:contains('"+aref+"'), h1:contains('"+aref+"')+p");
        $(".modal-footer").html("<button id=\"butt\" name=\""+aref+"\" value=\""+aref+"\">"+aref+" honours</button><div id=\"dead\"></div>");
      });
      $("#club_info .name:last-of-type").css({"margin-right":"50%"});
  }
  
  if(settings.url=="css/history.html"){
     $("#butt").click(function(){
      var testing=$(this).attr('value');
      var testclean=encodeURIComponent(testing);
 
      $.getJSON(url+"getHonours?name="+testclean, function(data){
        var honours=[];
      
        $.each(data, function(){ 
            
          honours.push("<table class=\"table\" id=\"honstab\"><tr><th>"+data[0]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[1]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[2]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[3]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[4]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[5]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[6]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[7]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[8]["Source"]+"</th></tr><tr><td>"+data[0]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[1]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[2]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[3]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[4]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[5]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[6]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[7]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[8]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td></tr></table>");
        
          $("#dead").html(honours.slice(0,1));
          $("#honstab td").each(function(){
            if ($(this).html()=="0"){
              trial=$(this).index();
              $("#honstab th:eq("+trial+"), #honstab td:eq("+trial+")").remove();
              if($("#honstab tr").html()==0){
                $("#honstab").html("<tr><th>No Honours</th></tr></table>");
              }
            }
          });
        });
      });
     });
  }

});

<!--Heres the view file-->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../docs-assets/ico/favicon.png">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <title>Connacht Senior League</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
        <link href="css/main-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
      
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="heading">
                    <h1>Connacht Senior League</h1>
                    
                  </div>
                
                  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="csl-navbar" role="navigation">
                      <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <!--creates the toggle button that displays the menu in small screen formats-->
                          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        </button>
                            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
                      </div>
                      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                         <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="false">
                            <li><a href="#home" value="home">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">History<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#eighties" value="eighties">Eighties Seasons</a></li>
            <li><a href="#nineties" value="nineties">Nineties Seasons</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
                            <li><a href="#clubs" value="clubs">Clubs</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#champions" value="champions">Champions</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#senior_cup" value="senior_cup">Senior-Cup</a></li>
                         </ul>
    <!-- for the search and go form on the right of navbar-->
                            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                              </div>
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
                            </form>
                     </div>
                  </nav>
           
                  <div id="home" class="views">
                    <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-12" id="home_text">
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-12" id="home_image">
                      <img src="images/home_page.png"/>
                     </div>
                     <div class="col-xs-12" id="ina_logo">
                      <img src="images/ina.PNG" width="30%"/>
                     </div>
                     </div>   
                  </div>
                  
                  <div id="eighties" class="views">
                     <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-12" id="eighties_text">
                     </div>
                     </div>   
                  </div>
                  <div id="nineties" class="views">
                     <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-12" id="nineties_text">
                     </div>
                     </div>   
                  </div>

                  <div id="clubs" class="views">
                     <div class="row">
                     <div class="col-xs-12">
                      <div id="club_info">

                      <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" id="modalCSL" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                          <div class="modal-content">
                            <div class="modal-body">
                            ...

                          </div>
                         <div class="modal-footer">

                          </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                  </div>

                  <div id="champions" class="views">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <h1>Champions</h1>
                        <p>The following table lists the League Champions and sides who finished Second. Goal differnece did not count so occassionally Play-offs were needed. An exception is the case of the 94-95 season where the League was split into two groups so a Play-off was mandatory. In 96-97 the season had Two divisions, the table only shows details of the Premier Division with First Division details in the footnotes</p>   
                      <table class="table table-striped" id="senior_champions">
                        <tr>
                         <th>Season</th>
                         <th>Winner</th>
                         <th>Runner-up</th>
                         <th>Play off</th>
                       </tr>
                      </table>
                      <div class="notes"><p><a name="merv_salt" id="merv_salt"></a>R: 2nd Replay after two 2-2 draws</p>
                        <p><a name="straide" id="straide"></a>Gr: League split into 2 groups with group winners meeting in a play-off final. Top 3 teams in each group would go into a Premiership and the rest into a first division</p>
                        <p><a name="prem" id="prem"></a>Pr: This season had a Premiership and a First Division. Ballinasloe Town were First Division Champs.</p>
                     </div>
                   </div>
                   </div>
                  </div>
                  
                  <div id="senior_cup" class="views">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-12">
                         <h1>Senior Cup</h1>
                        <p>The following table lists details of the Senior Cup Finals. This was the main knockout competition involving the Connacht Senior clubs. However champions from the four junior leagues were also included and they are highlighted with a (J)</p>
                    <table class="table table-striped" id="senior_cup_finals">
                      <tr>
                       <th>Season</th>
                       <th>Winner</th>
                       <th>Score</th>
                       <th>Runner-up</th>
                     </tr>
                    </table>
                    <div class="notes"><p><a name="calry_merv" id="calry_merv"></a>R: Replay after 1-1 draw</p>
                                          <p><a name="salt_calry" id="salt_calry"></a>R-p: Replay won on penalties after 1-1 draw</p>
                                        </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>

       <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" pause="onload">
         <!--  Wrapper for slides--> 
          <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            <div class="item active" id="pix1">
        
            </div>
            <div class="item" id="pix2">

            </div>
            <div class="item" id="pix3">

            </div>
            
          </div>

        </div>
</div>

       
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 9]><!-->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/csl.js" type="text/javascript">
 </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does it fail? What happens, what did you expect? "does not work" is not very specific.

Comment: Its not loading, jQuery load() works but not getJSON. The get JSON is supposed to populate tables but the cells are not appearing. The table headings are hard coded and the data under them is dynamically loaded when the website loads. They appear on both chrome, firefox and on an android browser.

Comment: Also I should say that no errors or failure reasons appear in the Internet Explorer Developer Tools Console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right then, it seems that IE had a problem with the js file. It does not like the fact I have the global 'url' variable outside of all functions. So I had to name this variable within the (document).ready(function{}). Also I had the ajaxSuccess and ajaxError functions operating on their own, they also needed to be brought within the (document).ready function, merely naming the url variable inside them individually did not work. Basically everything needs to be wrapped in one main function. this link here inspired the solution http://patrickgibson.com/news/andsuch/000202.php

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var url="../../index.php/cslcontrol/";
//$.ajaxSetup({ global: true });
  //hide divs with the class '.views' except the one with id of 'home'
  $(".views:not('#home')").hide();
  //function that ensures only the div related to the selected menubar icon is dislayed
  $("li a[href]").click(function(){
    //storing the value of the clicked list a href
    var tabVal=$(this).attr('value');
    //showing a div whose div name is the same as the value of the selected list ahref
    $("#"+tabVal).show();
    //keeping the other divs hidden
    $(".views[id!="+tabVal+"]").hide();
  });

  $("#home_text").load("css/history.html #home_txt");

  $("#eighties_text").load("images/Eighties_seasons.html h1, p");
  
  $("#nineties_text").load("images/Nineties_seasons.html h1, p");

//making a ajax call to fill the champions table
  $.getJSON(url+"titleWin", function(data){
   $.each(data, function(){
    $("#senior_champions").append("<tr><td>"+ this["Season"] + "</td><td>"+ this["Winner"] + "</td><td>" + this["Runner up"] + "</td><td>"+ this["Play off"] + "</td></tr>");
    });
  });
  //making a ajax call to fill the senior cup table

  $.getJSON(url+"senCup", function(data){
   $.each(data, function(){
    $("#senior_cup_finals").append("<tr><td>"+ this["Season"] + "</td><td>"+ this["Winner"] + "</td><td>" + this["Score"] + "</td><td>"+ this["Runner-up"] + "</td></tr>");
    });
  });
  $.getJSON(url+"getClub", function(data){
   $.each(data, function(){
    $("#club_info").append("<a class=\"name\" role=\"button\" data-toggle=\"modal\" data-target=\"#modalCSL\">"+this["Club"]+"</a>");
    });
   var crests = [];
   $.each(data, function(){
    if(this["Image"]!=""){
      crests.push("<img src=\"images/"+this["Image"]+"\" alt=\""+this["Image"]+"\" title=\""+this["Club"]+"\"/>");
    }
   });
   $("#pix1").html(crests.slice(0, 5));
   $("#pix2").html(crests.slice(5, 10));
   $("#pix3").html(crests.slice(10, 15));
  });
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event,xhr,settings){
//var json="http://davestest.webuda.com/index.php/cslcontrol/";
  //if(settings.url=="history.txt"){
    // $("#home_text").append("<div class=\"home-images\">do</div>");
  //}

  if(settings.url==url+"senCup"){
    $("#senior_cup_finals td:eq(26), #senior_cup_finals td:eq(30)").append("<a href=\"#calry_merv\"><sup> R</sup></a>");
    $("#senior_cup_finals td:eq(34)").append("<a href=\"#salt_calry\"><sup> R-p</sup></a>");
  }
  if(settings.url==url+"titleWin"){
    $("#champions td:eq(11)").append("<a href=\"#merv_salt\"><sup> R</sup></a>");
    $("#champions td:eq(52)").append("<a href=\"#straide\"><sup> Gr</sup></a>");
    $("#champions td:eq(56)").append("<a href=\"#prem\"><sup> Pr</sup></a>");
  }
  if(settings.url==url+"getClub"){
      $(".name").click(function(){
        var aref= $(this).text();
        $(".modal-body").load("css/history.html h1:contains('"+aref+"'), h1:contains('"+aref+"')+p");
        $(".modal-footer").html("<button id=\"butt\" name=\""+aref+"\" value=\""+aref+"\">"+aref+" honours</button><div id=\"dead\"></div>");
      });
      $("#club_info .name:last-of-type").css({"margin-right":"50%"});
  }
  
  if(settings.url=="css/history.html"){
     $("#butt").click(function(){
      var testing=$(this).attr('value');
      var testclean=encodeURIComponent(testing);
 
      $.getJSON(url+"getHonours?name="+testclean, function(data){
        var honours=[];
      
        $.each(data, function(){ 
            
          honours.push("<table class=\"table\" id=\"honstab\"><tr><th>"+data[0]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[1]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[2]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[3]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[4]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[5]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[6]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[7]["Source"]+"</th><th>"+data[8]["Source"]+"</th></tr><tr><td>"+data[0]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[1]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[2]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[3]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[4]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[5]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[6]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[7]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td><td>"+data[8]["COUNT(*)"]+"</td></tr></table>");
        
          $("#dead").html(honours.slice(0,1));
          $("#honstab td").each(function(){
            if ($(this).html()=="0"){
              trial=$(this).index();
              $("#honstab th:eq("+trial+"), #honstab td:eq("+trial+")").remove();
              if($("#honstab tr").html()==0){
                $("#honstab").html("<tr><th>No Honours</th></tr></table>");
              }
            }
          });
        });
      });
     });
  }

});
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqxhr, settings){
  if(settings.url==url+"senCup"){
    alert("not loading");
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Knockout binding and method ko.toJS in your view model js.